# NTCIP 1203v3 ambiguities

Tags: asn.1, mib

Is there consensus on how to interpret the various "bitmap" OCTET STRING objects in NTCIP 1203v3? When there is ambiguity without a consensus opinion, it is my assertion that the debated objects must be deprecated in the next version and central systems should avoid using them in the meantime.

**BACKGROUND:**

NTCIP 1203 defines several OCTET STRING objects and uses terms such as:

- Bit #
- low (or high) order bit

Technically, these terms are not defined in for an OCTET STRING. ASN.1 states "In specifying the encoding rules for an octetstring, the octets are referenced by the terms first octet and trailing octet, and the bits within an octet are referenced by the terms most significant bit and least significant bit." One can reasonably assume that “low order bit” is the same as “least significant bit,” but this term only has a precise definition within an octet, not over the entire string.

**ISSUE 1. Simple low/high order bit**

I believe there is universal consensus that “low (high) order bit” of a single OCTET STRING object means “the least (most) significant bit of the trailing (leading) octet.” This is the terminology used for the StatusMap objects and the characterBitmap object and results in the following:
characterBitmap: F = upper left pixel; 0 = subsequent pixels; L = lower right pixel; P = padding:

```
First Octet|Second Octet
msb..lsb msb..lsb
F0000000 000LPPPP
```

StatusMap: F = Index 1, 0 = subsequent index items; L = last index item; P = padding:

```
PPPPL000 0000000F
```

Yes, it’s annoying that these are reversed, but the wording in the standard is clearly reversed, so any interpretation has to reflect that. I think the above is a universal interpretation. Does anyone disagree?

**ISSUE 2. dmsSupportedMultiTags**

dmsSupportedMultiTags is an OCTET STRING (SIZE (4)). The definition states “This object is a bitmap representation of tag support." It then defines a series of Bit values, such as "Bit 11: new page [np]"

Although ASN.1 does not define bit numbers in this precise context, when using the "bstring" notation, the first bit listed is the high-order bit of the first byte and padding is added to the low-order bits of the last byte. This could imply a sequence where you start counting up starting with the high-order bit of the first octet to the low order bit and then to the second octet and so forth.

Another interpretation might be that "a bitmap representation" means it should be interpreted as an ASN.1 BIT STRING. ASN.1 states "The leading bit of the bit string is identified by the ‘number’ zero, with succeeding bits having successive values." In BER, the leading bit is placed in the most significant bit of the first octet. This is consistent with the previous paragraph and with the logic for characterBitmap.

However, I have heard some argue that "it is widely understood that Bit 0 is the low order bit of an integer." I will concede that this “two’s complement” logic is widely terminology, but this object is not defined as an INTEGER. The jump from OCTET STRING to INTEGER is much less obvious than OCTET STRING to BIT STRING, especially when the object could have been defined as a INTEGER.

Thus, I believe the correct interpretation is to encode the value as a BIT STRING where Bit 0 = F, Bit 29 = L and Padding = P:

```
F0000000 00000000 00000000 00000LPP
```

Is there universal consensus on this interpretation or do we need to deprecate this object?

**ISSUE 3. dmsPixelStatus**

In this case, we not only have ambiguous wording about bit and byte order, but we also have to deal with the logical ordering of the rows in the table. The definition states:

- The lowest-order bit corresponds to the top-left pixel of the sign face
- the next bit corresponds to the next pixel to the right, etc.
- At the end of a pixel row, the next bit corresponds to the leftmost bit of the row below.
- The last entry of this table does not need to be 400 octets but the preceding entries do.
- Any remaining bits within the final byte of the last entry of this table shall be zero.

I can see multiple interpretations, including, but not limited to (I limited each row of the table to 3 bytes rather than 400 for space):

```
00000000 00000000 0000000F
L0000000 0000PPPP
```

or

```
00000000 00000000 0000000F
PPPPL000 00000000
```

or

```
0000000F 00000000 00000000
00000000 PPPPL000
```

etc

My impression is that there is not consensus on this one, but I thought I'd ask the question to see what the community thinks.

Comment: I don't think you reach the "community" here. NTCIP.org or the author himself/herself should be a better contact.

Comment: Suggest you remove the asn.1 tag.  This is not at all a question about asn.1, it just happens that the protocol you feel has ambiguities is using ASN.1.

Comment: I placed the ASN.1 tag there in case anyone from that community wanted to pipe in as to whether my interpretation of that standard is correct. For example, if someone referenced Bit 11 of an ASN.1 OCTET STRING what would your first impression be? (And if it is "they don't know what they are talking about" I would agree, but is there any reasonable interpretation; or is it just flat out meaningless?)